# How to add Pagination?

Tags: php, html

I have this simple array and i want to add a pagination that displays what's inside the array by 2.

the number of page depends on how many is inside the array.

also this link "<<" displays the first page and this link ">>" displays the last page.

here is my code:

any solutions or ideas guys?

```
$arr = array(   "coffeebean" => "coffee", 
                            "sansrival" => "cakes",
                            "Kylo ren" => "starwars",
                            "2story" => "koreanfoods",
                            "mooon" => "moon",
                            "barak"=>"obama"                                
                            );
            //display
            display($arr);
            function display($arr){
                foreach($arr as $key => $val){
                echo "{$key} =  {$val}";
                echo "<br>";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Let me explain you logic:
```

1) Take count of array into a variable.

2) Count number of page from above variable.

3) Show pagination href links below the records.

4) If the page number is invalid, show page not found error.

```
<?php
$arr = array("coffeebean" => "coffee", "sansrival" => "cakes", "Kylo ren" => "starwars", "2story" => "koreanfoods", "mooon" => "moon", "barak" => "obama");

// display
$page = isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] > 0 ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;

function display($arr, $page = 1) {
    $start = ($page-1) * 2;
    $arr = array_slice($arr, $start, 2);
  foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    echo "{$key} =  {$val}";
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
$len = count($arr);
$pages = ceil($len/2);
if ($page > $pages OR $page < 1) {
    echo 'page not found';
}
else {
    display($arr, $page);
    for ($i=1; $i<=$pages ; $i++) {
        $current = ($i==$page) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        if ($current) {
            echo '<b>'.$i.'</b>';
        }
        else {
        ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped greatly. :D

Comment: @Boneyflesh, you are welcome.